# int does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, int

Hey guys this bug has been puzzling me for like 4 hours, and nothing I've tried works.

```
 SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@bookId",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int.ToString());
 id.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(id);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 book.BookId = new int(id.Value.ToString()); // <------ERROR
```

The error is:

> int does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Here are some of the other things I have tried:

```
int x = id.value.ToString();
int xi = Convert.ToInt32(x);

book.BookId = x;
```

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: i just added it to the question

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but wouldn't you need to do the following on the last line: book.Bookid = Convert.ToInt32(id)? assuming book.BookId is an int?

Comment: 'System.Data.SqlDbType.Int.ToString()' ????

Comment: .tostring i fixed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
book.BookId = Int32.Parse(id.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: I suspect `id.Value` is a boxed `int` or `int?` which might provide a more direct way to get the value.

Comment: Tryed this before get:FORMAT EXCEPTION was caught:    Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Then... your bookId entry in the database does not contain a string convertible to an integer. You should print your value to the output and see what it says

Answer (score 4):

Since none of the answers so far have actually explained what you are doing wrong - this occurs because you are trying to call a constructor of `int` and pass an argument. [As you can see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td2s409d.aspx), there is no `int` constructor that accepts a string argument (or any other type, for that matter).

There are a few ways of converting a string to an integer, but the most robust (as [already posted by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039618/1043198)) is to use `Int32.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 book.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);
```

Comment: INVALID Cast Excepion was caught: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure that your string contain an integer and you are ok with throwing an exception else, you can do :

```
string id = "55";
int x = Int32.Parse(id);
```

Else, cleaner you can manage the case where the string is not an integer :

```
        string id = "55";
        int x = 0;
        if(!Int32.TryParse(id, out x))
        {
            //Manage the special case here where id is not a int
        }
```

Comment: Um i removed the system.data.sqldbtype.int.tostring() to system.data.sqldbtype.int  checked database it was a int. now to fix this bloody tranaction. Still getting a error with the book.bookId!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This statement doesn't look correct

```
SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@bookId",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int.ToString());
```

I think you should change it either Int or String

```
SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@bookId",System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
```

Just change your statement

```
 book.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: give us a sec will let u know ok id.value.Tostring returns format exception and id.value returns Object cannot be cast from db NUll to other types

Comment: it means the return Id value is null. Check you stored procedure and make sure it returns some value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try any of this:

```
book.BookId = Int32.Parse(id.Value.ToString());
```

OR

```
book.BookId = (int)id.Value.ToString();
```

OR

```
book.BookId = int.Parse(id.Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are using ToString() to much. Try this:

```
SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@bookId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
id.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(id);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Int32.TryParse(id.Value.ToString(),out book.BookId);
```

Comment: have that exact code right now and it says: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: you are right SqlDbType.Int is definitly not the same as int therefore it cannot be casted directly. Changed my code.

Comment: wonko then how did u fix ur code or edit ur code care to ellaborate?

Comment: I changed the last line to parse the SqlDbType.Int as string.

Answer (score 0):

You must check to make sure that id.Value is not NULL. *After* you've made sure, then this should work:

```
book.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(id.Value);
```

or even

```
book.BookId = (int) id.Value;
```

**Edit**

If `Int32.Parse()` is throwing a format exception, you *must* be giving it something that is not an integer. You say you're confident that it's not `NULL`, so *what is it*?

Comment: it cant be null its auto incremented in the data base i was using a different stored procedure and it was working. but now iam using a transaction